# Camunda connector with Gradle returns "If you are using a connector, make sure theconnect process engine plugin is registered with the process engine"

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, camunda

I try to implement Camunda http-connector in my spring boot - Gradle based project, using the below Gradle configurations and dependencies the project builds correctly but when I run the project, it returns:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngineFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.camunda.bpm.engine.ParseException: ENGINE-09005 Could not parse BPMN process. Errors: 
* One of the attributes 'class', 'delegateExpression', 'type', or 'expression' is mandatory on serviceTask. If you are using a connector, make sure theconnect process engine plugin is registered with the process engine. | resource some-path\test.bpmn | line 27 | column 46
```

I used the steps in Camunda documentation. This is my `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.26'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.8'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "org.liquibase.gradle" version "2.0.2"
    id 'jacoco'
}
group = 'some-group'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    //mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "some-url"
    }
}

ext {
    sentryVersion = '5.3.0'
}

test {
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        html.enabled true
        csv.enabled false
    }
}

dependencies {


    // ==== Spring dependencies ====
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"

    // Sentry
    implementation "io.sentry:sentry-logback:$sentryVersion"


//    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest:7.17.0'

    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp:7.15.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm.extension:camunda-bpm-identity-keycloak:7.15.0'
//    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter:7.15.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.camunda.bpm.springboot/camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest
    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest:7.19.0'



// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.camunda.bpm/camunda-engine-plugin-connect
//    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine-plugin-connect:7.20.0-alpha2'

//    implementation 'com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:9.12'


    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
//    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm.extension:camunda-platform-7-keycloak:7.17.0'
    implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter:15.0.2'
//    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:5.5.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:2.6.2'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.5'



   implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-core:21.1.1'


    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm.extension:camunda-bpm-identity-keycloak:2.2.3'

    // Camunda Connector
    implementation 'org.camunda.connect:camunda-connect-http-client:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.connect:camunda-connect-soap-http-client:1.3.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.connect:camunda-connect-core:1.1.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine:7.15.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.spin:camunda-spin-core:1.9.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.spin:camunda-spin-dataformat-json-jackson:1.9.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.spin:camunda-spin-dataformat-xml-dom:1.9.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine-plugin-spin:7.15.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm:camunda-bom:7.15.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm.dmn:camunda-engine-dmn-bom:7.15.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.connect:camunda-connect-connectors-all:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine-plugin-connect:7.15.0'



    // Postgres JDBC
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtimeOnly 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.3'
    // Lombok
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
   implementation "org.keycloak:keycloak-admin-client:13.0.0"

}

def appProperties = new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().load(file("src/main/resources/application-local.yml").newInputStream())
def liquibaseProperties = new org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml().load(file("src/main/resources/liquibase.yaml").newInputStream())
diffChangeLog.dependsOn assemble

//liquibase {
//    activities {
//        main {
//            changeLogFile "src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes/V" + migrationNumber() + "_changelog.yaml"
//            referenceUrl 'hibernate:spring:' + liquibaseProperties.getAt("entities-package-path") + '?dialect=' + liquibaseProperties.dialect
//            url appProperties.spring.datasource.url
//            username appProperties.spring.datasource.username
//            password appProperties.spring.datasource.password
//            driver liquibaseProperties.driver
//        }
//    }
//}

static def migrationNumber() {
    def files = new File("src/main/resources/db/changelog/changes")
            .listFiles();

    if (files == null)
        return 0

    return files.size();
}
jar {
            enabled = true
     }
```

And this is my Camunda BPMN process file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bpmn2:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:camunda="http://camunda.org/schema/1.0/bpmn" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" id="_1bTwQUkWEeO-QfaFiKQ6Gw" targetNamespace="http://camunda.org/examples" exporter="Camunda Modeler" exporterVersion="5.15.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd">
      <bpmn2:message id="Message_3a4udev" name="Message_3a4udev" />
      <bpmn2:process id="CAMT_Management_Workflow_V1.0" name="CAMT_Management_Workflow_V1.0" isExecutable="true">
        <bpmn2:scriptTask id="scriptTask" name="Welcome Message" scriptFormat="groovy">
          <bpmn2:extensionElements>
            <camunda:inputOutput>
              <camunda:inputParameter name="player">
                <camunda:script scriptFormat="groovy">
                  players = ["Fritz", "Heinz", "Horst", "Klaus"]
                  players[new Random().nextInt(players.size())]
                </camunda:script>
              </camunda:inputParameter>
            </camunda:inputOutput>
          </bpmn2:extensionElements>
          <bpmn2:script>
            println "Hello $player! Welcome to our casino"
          </bpmn2:script>
        </bpmn2:scriptTask>
        <bpmn2:endEvent id="Event_0ze79i7">
          <bpmn2:incoming>Flow_16h5tsc</bpmn2:incoming>
        </bpmn2:endEvent>
        <bpmn2:startEvent id="Event_0dillfr">
          <bpmn2:outgoing>Flow_0vfmd2r</bpmn2:outgoing>
        </bpmn2:startEvent>
        <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="Flow_0vfmd2r" sourceRef="Event_0dillfr" targetRef="Activity_0vcor0x" />
        <bpmn2:serviceTask id="Activity_0vcor0x">
          <bpmn2:extensionElements>
            <camunda:connector>
              <camunda:inputOutput>
                <camunda:inputParameter name="method">POST</camunda:inputParameter>
                <camunda:inputParameter name="payload">{
      "assessmentRequestId": "CA-2309-03858",
      "emailType": "EMAIL_FOR_ASSESSMENT_UPDATE"
    }</camunda:inputParameter>
                <camunda:inputParameter name="url">http://localhost:8180/email/send-email</camunda:inputParameter>
              </camunda:inputOutput>
              <camunda:connectorId>http-connector</camunda:connectorId>
            </camunda:connector>
          </bpmn2:extensionElements>
          <bpmn2:incoming>Flow_0vfmd2r</bpmn2:incoming>
          <bpmn2:outgoing>Flow_16h5tsc</bpmn2:outgoing>
        </bpmn2:serviceTask>
        <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="Flow_16h5tsc" sourceRef="Activity_0vcor0x" targetRef="Event_0ze79i7" />
      </bpmn2:process>
      <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
        <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="CAMT_Management_Workflow_V1.0">
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_0dillfr_di" bpmnElement="Event_0dillfr">
            <dc:Bounds x="152" y="82" width="36" height="36" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Activity_0ok0d83_di" bpmnElement="Activity_0vcor0x">
            <dc:Bounds x="340" y="70" width="100" height="80" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="Event_0ze79i7_di" bpmnElement="Event_0ze79i7">
            <dc:Bounds x="602" y="102" width="36" height="36" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
          <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_0vfmd2r_di" bpmnElement="Flow_0vfmd2r">
            <di:waypoint x="188" y="100" />
            <di:waypoint x="259" y="100" />
            <di:waypoint x="259" y="110" />
            <di:waypoint x="340" y="110" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
          <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="Flow_16h5tsc_di" bpmnElement="Flow_16h5tsc">
            <di:waypoint x="440" y="110" />
            <di:waypoint x="526" y="110" />
            <di:waypoint x="526" y="120" />
            <di:waypoint x="602" y="120" />
          </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
        </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
      </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
    </bpmn2:definitions>
```